# Ordenar orden de salida de un array

Tags: java, hilos

Hola sigo encallada en algunas partes de mi programa y ahora tengo la siguiente parte de mi programa:

```
public class Relleus {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Testimoni c = new Testimoni();
    int numMembres = 5; //la familia pot ser més gran o més petita

    //Es creen el membres de la família, se'ls dona un nom i es posen a mirar la tele
    Corredor[] membre = new Corredor[numMembres];
        for(int i=1; i<numMembres; i++) {
        membre[i] = new Corredor(c);
        membre[i].setName("CORREDOR : "+i);
        membre[i].start();


    }
    //Esperem que tots acabin de mirar la tele
    for(int i=1; i<numMembres; i++) {
        membre[i].join();
    }

    System.out.println("Carrera acabada!!");

  }
}




public class Corredor extends Thread {

    Testimoni comandament;
    static int canal;

    public Corredor(Testimoni c) {
        comandament = c;
        canal = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
     // 3, 2, 1, go, go, go

       System.out.println("Escriu go a la pantalla..");



        int veces = comandament.agafa();
        System.out.println(getName() + " esta corren");

        //Mira la tele
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 350) + 300);  //utilitzem el mètode sleep per suspendre l'execució del Thread un temps aleatori de ms
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!!!");

        }
        if (veces == 0 || veces == 1 || veces == 2) {
            System.out.println("Pasa el testimoni al seguent corredor:");
            //Deixa el comandament
            comandament.deixa();

        } else {
            comandament.deixa();
        }
        {

        }
    }
}


public class Testimoni  {
   /*
    * Modifiqueu i afegiu el codi necessari per implementar la classe 
    * Comandament.
    */
    boolean avalible = true;
    int PasarTest = 0;

    synchronized int agafa() {

    while (avalible == false) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    avalible = false;
    notify();
    return PasarTest;

}

        synchronized void deixa() {
    avalible = true;
    ++ PasarTest;
    notify();
}
    }
```

Tengo un array que muestra 4 corredores.

corredor 1
corredor 2
corredor 3 
corredor 4

Pero cuando los muesta por pantalla me los mezcla.

Como puedo evitarlo?

Podéis darme alguna idea?

Son hilos y voy algo perdida. Seguro que es una tontería pero no sé como plantearlo la verdad..

gracias!

Comment: deberías añadir el código de la clase Corredor, pero seguramente tengas que sincronizar algún método. Del mismo modo deberías añadir la salida que obtienes y un ejemplo de la que deseas, para tener todos los datos

Comment: ya esta editado! :)

Comment: No especificas realmente lo que quieres lograr. Inicias 5 threads y todos imprimen su nombre en el metodo run es lógico que iran en desorden pues se ejecutan en forma concurrente, sino para que son threads?

Comment: es un ejercicio del colegio.. Solo sé que tengo que hacer que los hilos salgan ordenados. Se que no es logico ni normal.. pero el ejercicio me pide esto.

Comment: es decir me pide 5 hilos. Y que salgan por orden. :S

Comment: entonces transcribe el texto del ejercicio, tal vez pide alguna otra cosa

Comment: el ejercicio dice:
Vamos a simular una carrera de atletismo de 4x100
Tendremos que crear una clase Relleus que simule una carrera.
hace falta crear 4 corredores ( 4 Threads ) con dorsales del 1 al 4. Que empezaran con go!
Antes habra que dar el testimoni al dorsal uno el cual iniciara la carrera..

Comment: Se trata de una carrera de relevos. Solo un corredor puede estar corriendo el que tenga el testimoni,
Una vez completada la vuelta, el corredor pasara el testimoni al corredor al corredor que TENGA EL SIGUIENTE NUMERO DE DORSAL (dorsal +1 ) . Los corredores que no hayan corrido estaran estaran en la linea de salida esperando su turno, a la espera de recibir el testimoni.

Hace falta asegurarse que el testimoni no pase a otro corredor que no sea el que tenga el dorsal immediatamente superior.

Answer (score 0):

---

Saludos Montse Mkd.

Al iniciar todos los `Thread` no es posible saber con exactitud cuándo se ejecutará dicho hilo, lo único que sabemos es que el `Thread` se ejecutará apenas llamemos al método `start`, básicamente es normal que se ejecuten en desorden (por cuestiones de concurrencia).

Volviendo a tu caso y según entiendo, necesitas ejecutar todos los hilos al mismo tiempo, pero estos deben ejecutarse en orden, es decir, esperar a que el Corredor 1 termine de correr para que el siguiente corredor (con dorsal superior de +1, es decir el Corredor 2), comience a correr y así sucesivamente hasta finalizar.

Viendo tu código, me di cuenta que **nunca** haces la comprobación del corredor (aunque sí existe, pero no la tomaste en cuenta) justo aquí:

```
int veces = comandament.agafa();
```

Ese método retorna un entero (y a mi parecer es el número de corredor que debería correr según el orden), sin embargo, ¿qué pasaría si el Corredor 3 está listo para correr pero no es su turno? Justamente eso es lo que no estás verificando, **¡lo estás dejando correr!**

Después de realizar varias pruebas, creo que deberías tomar en cuenta agrégarle un ID (de tipo entero) a cada corredor, el cuál será su "número" y así saber quién es quién. Basándome en tu código, obtuve el siguiente resultado:

[image: img]

Como observas, la concurrencia sigue ahí, ya que que los 4 corredores (`Thread`) se ejecutaron en desorden, sin embargo, al momento de correr, lo hicieron en orden según su número de dorsal (`ID`).

Básicamente, sólo se agregó una variable de tipo entero a la clase `Corredor` y luego se utilizó un `while` para comprobar si el entero coincidía con su número de dorsal, y si es así, entonces es su turno y debe correr.

```
public class Corredor extends Thread {

    Testimoni comandament;
    static int canal; // esta variable no sé para qué la utilizarás
    int id;

    public Corredor(Testimoni c) {
        comandament = c;
        canal = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(getName() + " está listo para correr");

        while (comandament.agafa() != id) {
            comandament.PasarTest--;
            comandament.deixa();
        }

        System.out.println("¡" + getName() + " está corriendo!");

        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 350) + 300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("¡Error!");

        }

        comandament.deixa();
    }
}
```

Y la clase `Relleus`:

```
public class Relleus {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Testimoni c = new Testimoni();
        int numMembres = 4;

        Corredor[] membre = new Corredor[numMembres];
        for (int i = 0; i < numMembres; i++) {
            membre[i] = new Corredor(c);
            membre[i].id = i; // se agrega el ID según el orden
            membre[i].setName("CORREDOR " + (i + 1));
            membre[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numMembres; i++) {
            membre[i].join();
        }

        System.out.println("¡Carrera acabada!");
    }
}
```

El código que adjunté es sólo a método de ejemplo, puesto que no hay cambios drásticos en la estructura, simplemente se reciclaron métodos ya existentes para lograr el objetivo de explicar el porqué sucede tu problema, queda a tu disposición utilizarlo como desees, sin embargo, te recomiendo investigar por tu cuenta una mejor forma de acomodar la estructura de tu programa.

---

**Evidencia:**

[image: gif]

Comment: he copiado tal cual tu programa y no me funciona.. :S

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que te sucede? Yo lo corrí infinidad de veces y me generaba el mismo orden de salida, primero el 1, luego el 2 y así hasta que finalizaba

Comment: has realizado algun cambio en la clase testimoni?  Me sale el texto de listo para correr se inicia el primer hilo pero ninguno mas..

Comment: No, la clase `Testimoni` no la agregué por lo mismo, porque la dejé intacta, únicamente agregué un ID en la clase `Corredor` y modifiqué el `while` en el `run`. Y por último, asigné cada `ID` en la clase `Relleus`

Comment: Y también, modifiqué el contador del `for`, no me pareció correcto iniciar un arreglo de 5 espacios y dejar el espacio 0 vacío

Comment: Ah, y también modifiqué el `if` que está justo casi terminando el `run`, el que decía `veces == 0 || veces == 1`...

Comment: pues no me funciona xD

Comment: Revisa los cambios que te mencioné, acabo de probar nuevamente (esta vez copié exactamente el código que adjunté) y lo volví a probar, y obtuve los mismos resultados... tal vez requiera más detalles de cómo tienes el programa, o cómo requieres que funcione

Comment: Añadí un gif de evidencia al final de la respuesta, lo probé 4 veces...

Comment: probare de crear un nuevo proyecto. Te digo algo!